# MasterDetailPage with hamburger menu on the right

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to place the hamburger menu icon on the right like on the picture below. And the menu should slide from right to left.

I looked for a way to do this but it looks like a simple setting does not exist for this? I started a few days ago learning `Xamarin.Forms` and this is the first problem I got. I spent hours but without success...

If anyone knows a solution, please share.

[image: Right menu]

I tried [this](https://github.com/P3PPP/RightMasterDetailPageSample/tree/master/MdpRight) on Github but it has no effect at all and it also says:

> 'MasterDetailPageRenderer.MasterDetailPageRenderer()' is obsolete:
>   'This constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use
>   MasterDetailPageRenderer(Context) instead.'

And please don't tell me to use [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit). Something simple as this should be out of the box.

Comment: Your question is legitimate, asking for "MasterDetailPage with hamburger menu on the right" is fine. But "please don't tell me to use SlideOverKit. Something simple as this should be out of the box" is the cause for downvote. There isn't a simple solution. If you don't like that, don't use Xamarin.Forms, you can use Xamarin.Android or Android/Java or whatever that is intended for that case.

Comment: on the official Xamarin presentation they have suggested that if this is the use case you shouldn’t use Xamarin.Forms on that page. Again it doesn’t mean that this necessarily can’t be done in Xamarin.Forms but rather that it brings more trouble than it is worth. And you insist on the simple solution...

Comment: @IvanIčin I don't know how much experience you have but when designing software, extensibility should be one of the important aspects to think about. And I didn't know that a right aligned menu could lead to big problems. As I said: 'I started a few days ago learning Xamarin.Forms'. The only solution is to have specific Renderers for Android and iOS then?

Comment: yes the only possible way is to write your own renderer. Aside from purely theoretical principles, this control doesn't even exist on iOS, Apple doesn't provide it, you have to build it yourself. I assume your suggestion is that it was better not to be implemented in Xamarin.Forms at all and leave it to the users, right?

Comment: Now I start understanding your point :-). Not Xamarin but Android, iOS and UWP should have those functionalities. But I'm too optimistic I think about out of the box components, everything can be developed.

Comment: @IvanIčin It's apparently possible. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a way of doing this (as explained [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127645/masterdetailpage-icon-right-and-drawer-open-from-right-to-left)):

manifest:

```xml
<application android:label="Sanaap" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

MainView.xaml:

```xml
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="Sanaap.App.Views.MenuView" 
                  FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                  Title="Main">
```

One downside, `FlowDirection` must be set back to `LeftToRight` on all other `ContentPages`

Comment: Using RTL has severe effects on whole layout. If you wanted RTL it is then quite possible, but you have never mentioned that.

Comment: @IvanIčin If I set `FlowDirection="LeftToRight"` on each ContentPage, then everything should be fine I think? Only the top toolbar containing the menu will be `RTL`